# PFLogInViewController - Sign Up and Login with only Login Button

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am customizing the Parse PFLogInViewController and trying to make it so that the login button will trigger a query to see if the username already exists.  If it does exist, the normal login will proceed.  If it doesn't exist, then the user will be signed up.

I was originally having trouble with the asynch nature of the query, but I split the query out from my function so that doesn't seem to be a problem.  As you can see in the code I've duplicated the logInViewController function, so that the second version of it has an extra parameter `doesExist: Bool`.

When I test it out, the logic seems to follow everywhere when I look at the print logs, but the duplicated logInViewController function doesn't actually log the user in.

Appreciate any advice!

```
func signUpFunc(username: String, password: String) {

    //this is the sign up function

    print(username)
    print(password)

    print("this is the sign up function")

}

func doesUserExist(username: String, password: String) {

    var query = PFUser.query()
    query!.whereKey("username", equalTo: username)

    query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (users, error) -> Void in

        if let users = users {

            if users.count == 0 {

                self.signUpFunc(username, password: password)

            } else {

                print ("made it here")

                print(username)
                print(password)



                let testController = LoginViewController()
                self.logInViewController(true, logInController: testController, shouldBeginLogInWithUsername: username, password: password)



            }

        }

    })

}


func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController, shouldBeginLogInWithUsername username: String, password: String) -> Bool {

    //this function happens on the initial click of the login button

    self.doesUserExist(username, password: password)

    return false
}

func logInViewController(doesExist: Bool, logInController: PFLogInViewController, shouldBeginLogInWithUsername username: String, password: String) -> Bool {

    //this should actually log the user in or give error if user/pass combo is wrong

    print("made it to login")
    print(username)
    print(password)

    return true

}
```

Comment: I don't actually see anywhere that you call `loginWithUsernameInBackground:password:block`

Comment: Hi @Paulw11 I don't actually call it anywhere.  When using the PFLogInViewController, I think it has some function built in when the Login button is pressed, but I can't see it anywhere.  The only function I can find in the doc is that logInViewController(....shouldBeginLogInWithUsername....).  I'll try calling the loginWithUsernameInBackground to handle the login side and see if it works though.  Thanks!

Comment: You are replacing the functionality of the `PFLoginViewController` with your own view controller, so just ignore that class and use the methods that are available on `PFUser` directly

Answer (score 0):

Just try to login with credentials and work with the response code from Parse. But I wouldn't just create a new user because the user doesn't exits. You will end up with a lot more users just because a user had a typo in their login and will end up with a new user. I would ask them first.

```
func trySignIn() {
    // get string from textfiled
    PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground("user12", password: "user12") { (user, err) -> Void in
        if let error = err {
            if error.code == 101 {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "\(error.localizedDescription) - Should we creat an account for you?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                let signUpAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Sign up", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { UIAlertAction in
                    self.signUpUser("user12", password: "user12")
                })
                let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
                alert.addAction(signUpAction)
                alert.addAction(cancelAction)
                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        } else {
            print("logged in successfully")
        }
    }
}

func signUpUser(username: String, password: String){
    let userToSignUp = PFUser()
    userToSignUp.username = username
    userToSignUp.password = password
    userToSignUp.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, err) -> Void in
        if let error = err {
            self.showAlertViewWithError(error)
        } else {
            print("User signed up") // Show message to user
        }
    }
}
```